# DynamoDB returning internal server errors or timing out on some requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

We're getting this response for some requests to dynamodb:

```
{
        "type": "Error",
        "message": "Internal server error",
        "stack": "InternalServerError: Internal server error\n    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)\n    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)\n    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)\n    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)\n    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)\n    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)\n    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10\n    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)\n    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12)\n    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)",
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "time": "2022-07-29T12:06:33.648Z",
        "requestId": "G0UIJLLB6QA2PMHORNFSHQQV4RVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
        "statusCode": 500,
        "retryable": true
    },
```

This isn't consistent however, some of the requests go through fine, others timeout and then we get this error once in a while. The lambda is inside a VPC but I doubt it's an issue with that as some of the requests are going to Dynamodb just fine.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Comment: See [How do I resolve HTTP 5xx errors in Amazon DynamoDB?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dynamodb-http-5xx-errors/)

Answer (score 1):

It happens for many reasons. As one example, when new capacity (partitions) are being added to a table there's a cutover moment from old to new where you'll see this for a short period of time. It's a retryable exception. You should have your code retry and it will generally succeed in short order.

You can track how frequently it happens in CloudWatch. If it's really common and not just intermittent, that's more interesting.